# How to line up table column headers with content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

The following code correctly displays a table with the information I need; however, the column headers are *way* out of line and do not show up above the content as I'd like.

Keep in mind, I would also like to maintain the ability to scroll.

```
<div class="right_result">
                <?php
                    $orders =  get_orders_by_email($user->Username);
                    if(!empty($orders)):
                ?>
                <table id="order_table" class="display">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><strong>Order Number</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Property Address</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Notes</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $order->Order_Number; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $order->Order_Name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $order->Order_Status; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $order->Order_Notes_Public; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p>No order history to show.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

This is a little messy as I've been fooling around with it, but the accompanying CSS:

```
table.display{  
}
table.display thead { 
    display: table-header-group;
}
table.display tbody {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;  
  display: block;
}

table.display {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table.display td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
table.display thead{    
    color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `tbody` to `display: block;`, which means it will no longer act as a table and will not align with your headers. Remove this.

If you want a 250px scrollable then wrap your table in a div that is scrollable with that height.

```css
.right_result {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table.display { }

table.display thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

table.display {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table.display td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

table.display thead {
    color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_result">
    <table id="order_table" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Order Number</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Property Address</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Notes</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you want frozen table headers then you should create a separate table for just the headers. Then make another table for the data and wrap it in a scroll

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}

.right_result {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table { width: 100%;}

table.display thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    text-align: left;
}

table.display tbody {}

table.display {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.display td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table.display td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

table.display thead {
    color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%"><strong>Order Number</strong></th>
                <th width="25%"><strong>Property Address</strong></th>
                <th width="25%"><strong>Status</strong></th>
                <th width="25%"><strong>Notes</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="right_result">
        <table id="order_table" class="display">
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td width="25%">Data</td>
                    <td width="25%">Data</td>
                    <td width="25%">Data</td>
                    <td width="25%">Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                    <td>Data</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

able div. Then make sure that the table cells of both tables have the same widths.

Comment: I am using the fixed headers solution. How should I make sure they have the same widths? The bottom table with the content seems to look fine now, but the headers are way too wide. I'm using: table.display td to set the width.